# How objects are created in android studio using findViewById(R.id.xyz) and without using new

Tags: java, android

```
TextView quantityTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
```

When creating object for quantityTextView reference we use id from xml that is quantity_text_view but how object is created for it without using new keyword.

I have searched a lot but haven't found the solution. I'm new in Android Programming, if you know the answer please tell how you find the solution for it

Comment: I think because the object is actually on your layout file (xml) and have been created when you attach it to your activity or fragment (like `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_layout)`. So the code you mentioned above just to grab that object from xml, and place it into object inside your activity or fragment to be modified

Answer (score 1):

On your `onCreate` method you are doing something like that

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
}
```

on the line `setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);` you are setting the layout and then you just getting reference on elements from that layout

And because of the UI has been set you don't need to `create` something with the `new` keyword just to get the reference with the `findViewById`

If you want to add dynamically a layout element you will need to use the `new` keyword and then add that element on your layout

Answer (score 0):

You can use android-layout-finder to without using new keyword. https://www.buzzingandroid.com/tools/android-layout-finder/

Answer (score 0):

Declare in class:

```
private TextView quantityTextView; //this is already a object
```

In your `onCreate()` init the `View`:

```
TextView quantityTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
```

Now you can use `quantityTextView` anywhere without any new creation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add Textview dynamically you need to use Text view like this:

`TextView tv=new Textview(this);`

And if you want to inflate the `Textview` from the `XML` file then you need to use `TextView` like this:

`TextView quantityTextView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);`

Answer (score 0):

findViewById does nothing. It just looks through view hierarchy and returns reference to a view with requested viewId. View is already created and exists. If you do not call findViewById for some view nothing changes.

Views are inflated by LayoutInflator. When you call setContentView xml layout is parsed and view hierarchy is created.

attributes passed to Button's constructor by LayoutInflater. check LayoutInflator source code.